# Winform application "has stopped working" on launch. Only on other computers

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-express

This is my first application I have ever released. I built it with Visual Studio Express in c# using winform application.

I'm fairly new to this and I can't manage to find an answer to my problem.

When I try to open (launch) my application on various other computers I get a "Winformapplication has stopped working" and the application does not start. I have tried to include all the resources I use in the folder but still couldn't make this work.

Strangely enough, the application works on all the computers I have Visual Studio installed (at least I think so). It worked as well on a random laptop I tried it on and it does not have anything special I could figure out (no VSE installed).

So my question is pretty simple : how do I make this work ? what am I missing ?

I can provide more information about the application itself if required.

Thank you a lot.

edit: removed code as it was not relevant.

Comment: You need to have the [.NET Framework](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40773) installed.

Comment: some time your the target framework is not installed on other computers. In which .net framework you have created this application, try to install the same .net framework on other computers and check it again.

Comment: I have checked and they all have .NET 4.5 installed. At least I could not install the latest version since they already had it.

Comment: can you post Program.cs codes

Comment: Edit your question to add the code to it, it's unreadable in a comment. And then delete the comment.

Comment: The rest of my code (pretty much everything) is in the various forms I created.

Comment: The code you posted shows no useful information, `Form1` or some method that `Form1` calls is the source of your problem.

Comment: I thought so. Is there any way for me to find out which method might cause the problem ?

Comment: Wrap it in a try-catch and show us the stacktrace and exception message. Then we can help you.

Comment: Thanks! My software uses a database connexion to an Access Database and the error seems to be "'Microsoft Office 12.0 Access Database Engine OLE DB Provider' Provider is not registered on the local machine.".

Any lead on how I could fix this so it will work on any computer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My error came from : "'Microsoft Office 12.0 Access Database Engine OLE DB Provider' Provider is not registered on the local machine.

A temporary fix would be to install [2007 Office System Driver: Data Connectivity Components](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=23734) as stated on [this thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1d5c04c7-157f-4955-a14b-41d912d50a64/how-to-fix-error-the-microsoftaceoledb120-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine?forum=vstsdb).

Thanks for the help everyone.

I'm still looking for an alternative though.